# Python API: Temporal Type Conversion from Python to DolphinDB

Tags: python, import, dolphindb

When appending data to DolphinDB using Python API, I find it difficult to covert Python date, time and datetime objects into DolphinDB temporal types. For example, I want to convert the following types:

1. save 9:15 as MINUTE;
2. save 13:30:10.008 as TIME;
3. save 2012.06.13 13:30:10 as DATETIME;
4. save 2012.06.13 13:30:10.008 as TIMESTAMP.

I’m struggling with this problem. I wonder if there is any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temporal types of DolphinDB are showed as follows:

[image]

For example, I use function `pandas.read_csv` to read the data in Figure 2. The first four columns are recognized as string type, and the last two columns are recognized as int type, therefore, the following errors are raised when appending data to DolphinDB:

```
column 4, expect category TEMPORAL, got category INTEGRAL
```

or

```
column 1, expect category TEMPORAL, got category LITERAL
```

[image]

Here, I recommend an easy solution:

1. Convert Python datetime to np.datetime64;
2. Use objects [tableAppender](https://github.com/dolphindb/api_python3#64-automatic-temporal-data-type-conversion-with-the-tableappender-object) (to insert records in batches) or
   [MultithreadedTableWriter](https://github.com/dolphindb/api_python3#68-append-data-in-batch-asynchronously-with-the-multithreadedtablewriter-object) (to insert single record frequently) using
   Python API. These two objects support automatic data type conversion
   for both in-memory tables and DFS tables.

**Insert records in batches**

Take the following CSV file as an example:

```
minuteCol,timeCol,datetimeCol,timestampCol,allDigitalDate,allDigitaldateTime
9:15,13:30:10.008,2012.06.13 13:30:10,2012.06.13 13:30:10.008,20120613,20200101093000
9:16,13:30:10.009,2012.06.13 13:30:11,2012.06.13 13:30:10.009,20120614,20200101093001
```

The table has 6 columns. The expected DolphinDB data types should be (from left to right): MINUTE, TIME, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP, DATE, DATETIME.

Convert the data type of temporal columns into np.datetime64 with the following script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dolphindb as ddb

# read the csv file and convert the data type of temporal columns into np.datetime64
df = pd.read_csv("D:/pythontm/datetime.csv")

df['minuteCol'] = pd.to_datetime(df['minuteCol'])
df['timeCol'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timeCol'])
df['datetimeCol'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetimeCol'])
df['timestampCol'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestampCol'])
df['allDigitalDate'] = df['allDigitalDate'].astype('str')
df['allDigitalDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['allDigitalDate'])
df['allDigitaldateTime'] = df['allDigitaldateTime'].astype('str')
df['allDigitaldateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['allDigitaldateTime'])
```

- **Append data to DFS tables.**

(1) Create a distributed database and a DFS table. The data types of columns in table are specified as: MINUTE, TIME, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP, DATE, DATETIME.

```
# connect to DolphinDB server
s = ddb.session()
s.connect("192.168.100.3",20030,"admin","123456")

# create a DFS table
script_dfs = """
    if(existsDatabase("dfs://dtDfs"))
    {
        dropDatabase("dfs://dtDfs")
    }
    db = database("dfs://dtDfs",VALUE,2021.02.21..2021.02.22)
    sch = table(1:0,`minuteCol`timeCol`datetimeCol`timestampCol`digitalDate`DigitalDatetime,`MINUTE`TIME`DATETIME`TIMESTAMP`DATE`DATETIME)
    db.createPartitionedTable(sch,`dt,`datetimeCol)    
"""
s.run(script_dfs)
```

(2) Define a tableAppender object and append data to the DolphinDB DFS table.

```
appender_dfs = ddb.tableAppender("dfs://dtDfs","dt", s)
appender_dfs.append(df)
```

(3) Query the new DFS table with DolphinDB GUI or VSCode.

```
login(`admin，`123456)
select * from loadTable("dfs://dtDfs",`dt)
```

Output

[image]

- **Append data to in-memory tables.**

(1) Create an in-memory table.

```
script = """
    share table(1:0,`minuteCol`timeCol`datetimeCol`timestampCol`digitalDate`DigitalDatetime,`MINUTE`TIME`DATETIME`TIMESTAMP`DATE`DATETIME) as dtTable
"""
s.run(script)
```

(2) Define a tableAppender object and append data to the DolphinDB in-memory table.

```
appender = ddb.tableAppender(tableName="dtTable", ddbSession=s)
appender.append(df)
```

(3) Query the new in-memory table with DolphinDB GUI or VSCode.

```
select * from dtTable
```

Output

[image]

**Insert single record frequently**

The time taken to import 1 record and 1000 records to a DFS table on the disk is almost the same, which means that inserting each record with tableAppender will be time-consuming. Frequent writes to the disk can be a bottleneck.

Therefore, MultithreadedTableWriter is recommended to insert single record frequently.

(1) Create a DFS table. The data types of columns in table are specified as: MINUTE, TIME, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP, DATE, DATETIME.

```
import numpy as np
import dolphindb as ddb
import time
import datetime

# connect to DolphinDB server
s = ddb.session()
s.connect("192.168.100.3",20030,"admin","123456")

# create a DFS table
script_dfs = """
    if(existsDatabase("dfs://dtDfs_mtw"))
    {
        dropDatabase("dfs://dtDfs_mtw")
    }
    db = database("dfs://dtDfs_mtw",VALUE,2021.02.21..2021.02.22)
    sch = table(1:0,`minuteCol`timeCol`datetimeCol`timestampCol`digitalDate`DigitalDatetime,`MINUTE`TIME`DATETIME`TIMESTAMP`DATE`DATETIME)
    db.createPartitionedTable(sch,`dt,`datetimeCol)    
"""
s.run(script_dfs)
```

(2) Create a MultithreadedTableWriter object.

```
# insert data with MTW object
writer1 = ddb.MultithreadedTableWriter("192.168.100.3",20030,"admin","123456","dfs://dtDfs_mtw","dt",False,False,[],10000,1,5,"datetimeCol")
```

(3) Use a for loop to read the current time 1000 times and convert the type to np.datetime64, keeping the same number of columns as the DFS table.

```
try:
    for i in range(1000):
        writer1.insert(np.datetime64(datetime.datetime.now()),np.datetime64(datetime.datetime.now()),np.datetime64(datetime.datetime.now()),\
            np.datetime64(datetime.datetime.now()),np.datetime64(datetime.datetime.now()),np.datetime64(datetime.datetime.now()))
        time.sleep(0.01)
except Exception as ex:
    # MTW throws an exception
    print("MTW exit with exception %s" % ex)
```

(4) Submit and wait for the completion.

```
writer1.waitForThreadCompletion()
writeStatus=writer1.getStatus()
if writeStatus.hasError():
    print("Error in writing:")
print(writeStatus)
```

(5) Print the write status. An errorCode of None indicates the write is successfully done.

[image]

(6) Check the new in-memory table with DolphinDB GUI or VSCode.

```
login(`admin,`123456)
select * from loadTable("dfs://dtDfs_mtw",`dt)
```

Output:

[image]